ARM install shared libraries not found
Fresh gazebo harmonic install on a Ubuntu 22.04 VM on a M2 chip will result in the following :
Virtual-Machine:~/Documents/proto$ gz sim world_demo.sdf 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
[Err] [SystemLoader.cc:92] Failed to load system plugin [MinimalScene] : Could not find shared library.
[Err] [SystemLoader.cc:92] Failed to load system plugin [GzSceneManager] : Could not find shared library.
[Err] [SystemLoader.cc:92] Failed to load system plugin [WorldControl] : Could not find shared library.
[Err] [SystemLoader.cc:92] Failed to load system plugin [WorldStats] : Could not find shared library.
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
libEGL warning: NEEDS EXTENSION: falling back to kms_swrast

Installation is successful and the shared libraries are in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/
My question is : Which gazebo environment variable should I specify this path to ?
I think that could solve the problem.  Do you have any other ideas ?
I understood from Finding ressource that the system plugins are to be specified in GZ_SIM_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH but that doesn't work for normal plugins after I tried.
Thank you for your help!
